# Appending a table to webpage

Tags: jquery, html

The issue with the table results has been sorted. But there is an issue with the results displaying above the button. I have played about with the positioning of the CSS to see if that makes a difference but to no avail.

Button Above

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Wresults').click(function(){  
            $('#content').append('<ul />');
            $('span[class="womens_name"]').each(function(){
               $('#content ul:last-child').append('<li>' + $(this).text()  + '</li>' );
            }); 
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
        <input type='button' value='Womens Results' id='Wresults'/>
        <div id="textHolder">
        <section id="womens_results">
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Rachael Armstrong - 22:19</span>
        </article>
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Christine Boyd: 31:30</span>
        </article>
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Jane Jameson - 28:18</span>
        </article>
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Lucy McMullan - 26:09</span>
        </article>
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Alice Wonderland - 18:58</span>
        </article>
        <article>
            <span class="womens_name">Jane Jameson - 24:41</span>
        </article>
        </section>

        <div id="content">
        </div>
```

CSS

```
ul:last-child { 

     -moz-column-count: 4;
     -moz-column-gap: 20px;
     -webkit-column-count: 4;
     -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
     column-count: 2;
     column-gap: 10px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 #Mresults {

    margin-left: 360px;
}
```

Comment: Is that your full html code? Looks like your missing table to append anything to.

Comment: The table is created in the jQuery - $('#content').append('<table border="1" />');

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop over all `<article>`s and then get the name and time within each article to use as the text for the table cells.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var resultsTable;
    
    $('#Mresults').click(function(){
      if (typeof resultsTable == "undefined") {
        resultsTable = $('<table border="1" id="resultsTable" />').append('<tr><th>Competitor</th><th>Time</th></tr>').appendTo('#content');
      }
      $('#mens_results article').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        resultsTable.append('<tr><td>' + $this.find('.mens_name').text()  + '</td><td>' + $this.find('.mens_time').text() + '</td></tr>' );
      }); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Mens Results' id='Mresults' />
<div id="textHolder">
    <section id="mens_results">
    <article>
        <span class="mens_name"> Ben Chalmers</span>
        <span class="mens_time"> 30:00</span>
    </article>
    </section>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's worked well for. However, one more small issue. When I click the button, the results (table) appears above the button. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not the case for me... when I click the button, the table appears below the button. Firefox as well as Chrome.

Comment: Still having trouble with the results being displayed above the button. More code has been added to the edited version of the question.

Comment: Even copying your new code to a fiddle, the data was being appended to the table below the button. So I can only assume that there is another table in your page, and in the former version of the code (the one based on that in your question), you were adding to just any table tag on the page. I now changed the code to make the table have an ID and only append to that newly created table.